# Make, implicit rules for files in different directories

Tags: makefile, dependencies

I am trying to automatically generate dependencies with `make` by following the steps described in http://www.microhowto.info/howto/automatically_generate_makefile_dependencies.html . For a simple case where the source and objects files are all in the same directory, the method provided is working. However, if I have the following file tree:

- src

  - helloworld.cpp
  - makefile
- bin

and if I use the following makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS += -MD -MP
BIN_DIR=../bin

SRC = $(wildcard *.c)

hello_world: $(SRC:%.c=$(BIN_DIR)/%.o)
    $(LD) -o $@ $^

-include $(SRC:%.c=$(BIN_DIR)/%.d)
```

Then I get this error message:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `../bin/helloworld.o', needed by `hello_world'. Stop.
```

And no .d files are generated.

As I understand it, the problem comes when trying to apply an implicit rule to generate `../bin/helloworld.o`, since the corresponding source file is `helloworld.cpp`, and not `../bin/helloworld.cpp`.

Is it possible to describe to make that I want an implicit rule using two files that are not in the same directory ?

Comment: Is it `hello_world` or `helloworld`? The error message is not consistent with the Makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible: add a rule for `$(SRC:%.c=$(BIN_DIR)/%.o)`.

It is *not* to be recommended: it is not common practice, and neither is the idea to have `*.o` files in a `bin` directory.

Common practice is to have `make` read and write files in the same directory, and once everything is compiled, use a separate `install` step that copies the compiled software to a final location, usually called [`$(DESTDIR)`](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/DESTDIR.html).